# unable to create EC2 instance through knife

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, knife

I am creating an ec2 instance through knife . i gave the following command to create

```
knife ec2 server create -r "role[webserver]" -I ami-b84e04ea --flavor t1.micro --region ap-southeast-1 -G default -x ubuntu -N server01 -S ec2keypair
```

but getting error as **Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: InvalidBlockDeviceMapping => iops must be specified with the volumeType of device '/dev/sda1'** . I am unable to solve this issue , Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that the ami you are trying to launch requires an EBS. With an EBS you can set the IOPS value which seems like it is not set and is giving you the issue.

Having a look at the documentation it seems you might need to add

```
--ebs-size 10
SIZE as an option.
```

I got that from the knife documentation
http://docs.opscode.com/plugin_knife_ec2.html

Also taking a look at the source code for the knife ec2 plugin it looks like you can add.

```
--ebs-optimized 
Enabled optimized EBS I/O
```